# Map array of C structs in struct to Cython

Tags: python, c, struct, cython

**UPDATE**
Minimal example on GitHub: https://github.com/wl2776/cython_error

I've got a C library, that I want to access from Python. I'm developing a Cython wrappers for it.

The library has following declarations:

file "globals.h"

```
typedef struct
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int radius;
} circleData;
```

file "O_Recognition.h"

```
#include "globals.h"
typedef struct 
{
   int obj_count;
   circleData circle_data[2];
   float parameters[2];
} objectData;
```

I'm mapping these types to Cython in .pxd file, as follows:

file "cO_Recognition.pxd":

```
cdef extern from "globals.h":
    ctypedef struct circleData:
        int x;
        int y;
        int radius;

cdef extern from "O_Recognition.h":
    ctypedef struct objectData:
        int obj_count;
        circleData circle_data[2];
        float parameters[2];
```

And this does not compile. I am getting errors:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    void PyTuple_SET_ITEM(object  p, Py_ssize_t pos, object o)
    void PyList_SET_ITEM(object  p, Py_ssize_t pos, object o)

@cname("__Pyx_carray_to_py_circleData")
cdef inline list __Pyx_carray_to_py_circleData(circleData *v, Py_ssize_t length):
                                                ^
------------------------------------------------------------
carray.to_py:112:45 'circleData' is not a type identifier
```

One more detail, this is a part of the CMake project, that is built using this example from GitHub: https://github.com/thewtex/cython-cmake-example

Relevant part of CMakeLists.txt includes .pyx file with other name, that `cimport`s this cDeclarations.pxd

Comment: Adding some include guards to the c headers, I compiled your codes successfully in jupyter notebook.(cython0.25.2 + vs2015)

Comment: @oz1, I've added details. These declarations are in .pxd file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `circleData` is undefined in the `O_Recognition.h` extern block. Its previous definition only applies to the `globals.h` extern block.

Just need to include its type so that Cython knows what it is. It does not need to be re-defined.

```
cdef extern from "globals.h" nogil:
    ctypedef struct circleData:
        int x;
        int y;
        int radius;

cdef extern from "O_Recognition.h" nogil:
    ctypedef struct circleData:
        pass
    ctypedef struct objectData:
        int obj_count;
        circleData circle_data[2];
        float parameters[2];
```

When the code is compiled, the `.c` file will `include` both header files and get the type definition for circleData from `globals.h`.

Technically, the definition of `circleData` members in `globals.h` extern block is not needed either *unless* the structure members are going to be used in Cython code.

Remember, `pxd` files are definitions of Cython code, not C code. Only include members that are to be used in Cython code, otherwise can just define the type sans members per `circleData` per recognition extern block above.